# SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER, playwright python inside docker

Tags: python, docker, playwright, playwright-python

My code is quite simple:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
pw = sync_playwright().start()
firefox = pw.firefox.launch(headless=True)
context=firefox.new_context()
page= context.new_page()

page.goto("http://www.uaf.cl/prensa/sanciones_new.aspx")
```

Every single time I get a SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER.

Anyone know how I can bypass this? This is running inside a Docker container with `update-ca-certificates`.
I've tried using the "ignore HTTPS errors" option inside the context, to no avail(I need to access the webpage in spite of the error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with:

```
context=firefox.new_context(ignore_https_errors=True)
```